# SSRS - Matrix with multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I currently have an existing SSRS report which uses 2 datasets of data from a stored procedure, which is then aggregated in a bunch of matrix tables which automatically splits out columns by calendar months.

I have been asked to add a row from another table, and can add in the column through the Expression feature, but this does not take account of the month split, so it just adds in the total and repeats it for every column. Is there a way for it to be grouped by the month (month column is common between the two datasets, and they both run for the same time period.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an outer column group. You already have one by day, I guess. If you add another column group and make it grouped by YYYY-MM or another  unique value then you can drop the SUM(Fields!ValueToSumByMonth.Value) in the new groups footer (add subtotal - after).